# Require classes not working on PHP View Page

Tags: php

I don't know why my classes failed to load because of my folder structure it works in some places but not in some other places.
below is my folder

classes/
Rating.php

```
class Rating
{
public __construct($conn){
 $this->conn = $conn
 }
}
```

autolader/
class_Autoloader.php

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class_name){
include '../classes/'. $class_name'. '.php';
});
```

product.php

```
require 'autoloader/class_autoloader.php';
```

I now needed to add the spl_autoloader function to the product page before it worked. Also after uploading my code to Heroku my product page is not working. i will be glad if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the path like this;

```
 <?php
 $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/thefolderyourscriptisin/";
 require_once ($path."myscript.php");
 ?>
```

Comment: is there a way you can take a look at my code for me

Comment: the above solution did not work but I was able to find a way around it by using `require_once` instead of `require` I don't 100% know why it worked but it worked thank you very much. I tried reading up on why but I don't understand how `require `loads the classes more than once from what I read